# update and delete (single query) (EF + .NET Core Api)

Tags: reactjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

what's up? I have an **API** made with **.NET Core API + EF** where I have a **Many-to-Many** relationship between **Doctor** and **Specialty**, from which a **DoctorSpecialities** table arises. That is, a doctor can have several specialties.

I use **React JS** and what I want to do is have in the interface, a table with the specialties of the chosen doctor and when I send the form, the data in the **DoctorSpecialities** table is updated or deleted.

If the user deleted or added specialties, can all that be done in a single query?

My question is how to do the controller method, with that I have problems.

[image]

**Doctor**

```
public partial class Doctor
{
    public Doctor()
    {
        DoctorSpecialties = new HashSet<DoctorSpecialties>();
    }

    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public string DoctorName { get; set; }
    public string DoctorProfileImg { get; set; }
    public string DoctorPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string DoctorEmail { get; set; }
    public string DoctorStatus { get; set; }
    public string DoctorGender { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DoctorSpecialties> DoctorSpecialties { get; set; }
}
```

**Specialty**

```
public partial class Specialty
{
    public Specialty()
    {
        DoctorSpecialties = new HashSet<DoctorSpecialties>();
    }


    public int SpecialtyId { get; set; }
    public string SpecialtyName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DoctorSpecialties> DoctorSpecialties { get; set; }
}
```

**DoctorSpecialties**

```
public partial class DoctorSpecialties
{
    public DoctorSpecialties()
    {
        Appointment = new HashSet<Appointment>();
        DoctorSchedule = new HashSet<DoctorSchedule>();
    }

    public int DoctorSpecialtiesId { get; set; }
    public int? DoctorId { get; set; }
    public int? SpecialtyId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    public Specialty Specialty { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Appointment> Appointment { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DoctorSchedule> DoctorSchedule { get; set; }
}
```

**Context**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DoctorSpecialties>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("doctor_specialties");

        entity.Property(e => e.DoctorSpecialtiesId).HasColumnName("doctor_specialties_id");

        entity.Property(e => e.DoctorId).HasColumnName("doctor_id");

        entity.Property(e => e.SpecialtyId).HasColumnName("specialty_id");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Doctor)
            .WithMany(p => p.DoctorSpecialties)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DoctorId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK__doctor_sp__docto__2A4B4B5E");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Specialty)
            .WithMany(p => p.DoctorSpecialties)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.SpecialtyId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK__doctor_sp__speci__29572725");
    });
```

I tried with:

```
[HttpPut("test/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, Doctor doctor)
    {
        if (id != doctor.DoctorId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                Doctor plantToBeUpdated = await _context.Doctor.Include(p => p.DoctorSpecialties).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.DoctorId == id);

                if (plantToBeUpdated != null)
                {
                    plantToBeUpdated.DoctorSpecialties.Clear(); 

                    if (doctor.DoctorSpecialties.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var scId in doctor.DoctorSpecialties)
                        {
                            plantToBeUpdated.DoctorSpecialties.Add(new DoctorSpecialties()
                            {
                                DoctorId = plantToBeUpdated.DoctorId,
                                SpecialtyId = scId.SpecialtyId
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    plantToBeUpdated.DoctorName = doctor.DoctorName;
                    
                    _context.Doctor.Update(plantToBeUpdated);

                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }

            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return Ok(doctor);
    }
```

but, doesn't work :c

Comment: You'll need to fetch the DoctorSpecialties entities from the database and compare them with the ones sent by the front-end, marking them as inserted or deleted as necessary.

Comment: Please, can u help me with the code? I've tried, but can't.  :c

Comment: Can you post your controller code where you try?

Comment: Yes, you can see, please. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: I use Postman, I have sent the JSON with the modified data and it does not work. Sorry, my English is not that good.

Comment: What about the RI that hangs off the doctor_specialties table, (Appointments and schedules tables)?  you'd have to delete all those related entities too.

Comment: yes, no problem, can u help me please? I still can't find the solution.